# Why is it saying my questions.map() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-hooks

The area where the problem occurs is commented.
This is My React Component:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';


const ListQ = () => {
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);

const getQuestions = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/questions")
        const jsonData = await response.json();

        setQuestions(jsonData)
        console.log(questions)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
    }
}

console.log(questions)
useEffect(() => {
    getQuestions();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [])
//brackets for only 1 request

return (

    <Fragment>
        {" "}
        <table className="table table-dark table-hover mt-5 text-center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
```

//PROBLEM IS BELOW//

```
                {questions.map(question => (
                    <tr key={question.question_id}>
                        <td>{question.description}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button className="btn btn-warning">
                                Edit
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button className="btn btn-danger" >
                                Delete
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </Fragment>
)}export default ListQ;
```

It says it is a type error, but on my last project I put the first part of my useState array into a map function and there were no errors.

Comment: This means that `questions` is not an array. What is the structure of `questions` you're fetching?

Comment: BTW, you'll probably have to do a useCallback hook for your questions function and then put the function in the useEffect alongside the dependency. Disabling eslint complaints doesn't fix the problem :).

Comment: I think the problem is the data return from API is not a array yet, something like `{status: ..., data: [...]}` you should access the data to pull the questions list out.

Comment: @BlackMath Its the first part of my useState array, is there another way i can do this?

Comment: @ TonyDrummond Thanks I will Implement that!

Comment: @thelonglqd that makes sense, but if I am trying to map the questions element in useState how put an array in an array?

Comment: @BilalAbraham .map would be a function of questions initially because questions is set to an array by default in your useState. What does your API return? Console log the response from the API and modify this post to include it.

Comment: @BilalAbraham: what do you mean array in an array ?

Comment: @BilalAbraham You define the initial state as an empty array, but the returned data is not. What the log gives in `getQuestions`?

Comment: @TonyDrummond My API's .get() method returns all the questions stored in my db

Comment: @BilalAbraham I understand that. We need to see the response from your database. console log jsonData and edit your question to include the full response.

Comment: @BlackMath when I log questions in getQuestions I get random stuff:Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object

Comment: @TonyDrummond that must be whats wrong because im now getting the promise stuff: Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object

Comment: @BilalAbraham looks like you're on track in solving the issue now.

Comment: @TonyDrummond Thank You!